# Почему возникает ошибка cs0116?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Только начала изучать С# и наткнулась на пример, который не работает. Выдает ошибку "A namespace cannot directly contain members such a fields or methods". С помощью гугла определила, что это потому, что какой-то из методов не определен внутри класса, но я настолько начинающая, что не вижу, где ошибка в этом коде. Была бы признательна за любую помощь!

```
public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string levelName;

    void Start ()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    
    }
}
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == 'Player')
            other.transform.Translate(0, 5, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Оффтоп: Лучше вместо other.tag == "Player" писать other.CompareTag("Player") так не будет лишнего выделения памяти.

Comment: @Qwer где там выделение памяти вы увидели? Оператор точно так же работает как метод. Если уж на то пошло, лучше от строковых операций вообще избавиться и не сравнивать их ради производительности. Но ваш совет с реальностью не стыкуется. Дайте хоть почитать, где оно есть в документации, это выделение памяти, и самое интересное, подо что выделение может произойти при сравнении 2 строковых констант.

Comment: @aepot  Добро пожаловать в мир Юнити! В том-то и подвох, что нормальный программист не ожидает аллокации в таком тривиальном коде.

Comment: @aepot `Another unexpected cause of heap allocations can be found in the functions GameObject.name or GameObject.tag. Both of these are accessors that return new strings, which means that calling these functions will generate garbage. Caching the value may be useful, but in this case there is a related Unity function that we can use instead. To check a GameObject’s tag against a value without generating garbage, we can use GameObject.CompareTag().` [https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/fixing-performance-problems#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b595]

Comment: @Qwer спасибо, почитаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться в этом коде, достаточно было его отформатировать нормально. Вы вставили метод за пределами класса `Jump`.

Внимание на фигурные скобки у вас в вопросе и здесь.

```
public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string levelName;

    void Start ()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
            other.transform.Translate(0, 5, 0);
    }
}
```

Еще литералы типа `string` в C# пишутся в двойных кавычках.